# Changing color of bottom border on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/KuXZVpITPqEX0JrfYVBB?p=preview) I have a div that's resizable at the bottom border (using jQueryUI). What I need is to change the color of the *bottom border* when the mouse hovers it. Note that when the div is hovered over other borders, the color of the bottom border should not change.

Mouseover events work at the element level, not at the border level, so I'm not sure this can be achieved. Any ideas?

HTML

```
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Javascript

```
  $(".div2").resizable({ 
    handles: "s"
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pseudoelement.

You create the border to show on hover, position it in relation to the handle, and set it to be transparent until it's hovered over:

[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/o0UKLPmCyigUMNelQsrT?p=preview)

Relevent CSS:

```
  .ui-resizable-handle:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }

  .ui-resizable-handle:hover:after {
    background: blue;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick css hack might do the job - hover style changes bottom border on mouse hover and then active switches it back to the original color when it is being resized.

```
.div2:hover {
  border-bottom-color: green;
}

.div2:active {
  border-bottom-color: solid orange;
}
```

Comment: In your answer the bottom border color will change when the user hovers the entire div, I need to change the color only when the user hovers the bottom border.

Comment: Sorry I missed that nuance. The answer does from @sol does the job nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to try something as simple as this

```js
$(".div2").resizable({ 
    handles: "s"
  });

function borderOver() {
    document.getElementById("div2").style.border-bottom = "solid, red, 1px";
}

function borderOut() {
  document.getElementById("div2").style.border-bottom = "solid, white, 1px";
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="borderOver()" onmouseout="borderOut()" class="div2" id="div2"></div>
```